# how to add checkmark on UIActionsheet's buttons where i can create tick label in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactionsheet

I am trying to figure out how to add a checkmark to the right side of a button in a UIActionSheet.
Is there a safe way to add this checkmark in UIActionSheet's Button?
is there any simpler way to do add checkmark in UIActionsheet's buttons without using Of Private api ?

Comment: is there any problem to use the unicode checkmarks as part of the button's text? like ✓ or ✔?

Comment: @holex i have already try this method but not work any other way...

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 8.0 you can use `UIAlertController`. In `UIAlertController`, each button item is know as UIAlertAction which add accordingly. UIAlertAction contains a runtime property called image which you can set as per your need.

```
 UIAlertAction *SwipeView =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Swipe View" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {


}];
[SwipeView setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_mark" ] forKey:@"_image"];
```