# Showing Clickable URLs and icon in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, nstextattachment, tttattributedlabel

I am using `TTTAttributedLabel` for URLs and phone number in my app. Every thing is working fine but the problem is that now I need to show icon in the `UILabel`. Before I am using given below code. But due to use of `TTTAttributedLabel` now `NSTextAttachment` is not showing in `TTTAttributedLabel`. `TTTAttributedLabel` does not support attachment. So any idea to support URLs, phone numbers and icons in `UILabel`?

---

now i decided to show unicode image in TTTAttributedLabel. and it is working fine.

Comment: Have a look at this [Topic] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130475/adding-images-to-uiactionsheet-buttons-as-in-uidocumentinteractioncontroller) specifically the answer by Eddie. I use it and it has been approved in my most recent application. Just take heed to the warnings. There is a variance in OSs so it can alter without notice to you. But it could potentially fit in the scope of your goal.

Comment: thanks i think i can use unicode

Comment: but how to use it. i set \u1F318 and it shows me different thing in iphone simulator as given in documnetation

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use UITextView and set the textView's data detector types.

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAddress | UIDataDetectorTypeLink |     UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

There is one delegate methods that is called when the link or url in the text view is selected

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

This gives you the URL tapped inside your text view and you can perform your desired action.